# Popextender closes the panel after commit

Tags: asp.net

I'm creating a panel with a multi select CheckBoxList, attached to a TextBox through a PopControl extender.

I'm using the `.commit()` method of the `PopControl` extender to display the selected item.

When I select an item from the CheckBoxist the panel closes, and I want to select the item without closing the panel.

What am I doing wrong?

**Markup**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server" Skinid="longTextbox" AutoPostBack = "false" OnClientItemSelected="passtohidden()" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlLocation" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upLocation">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkLocation" SkinID ="chkColor" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true" onselectedindexchanged="chkLocation_SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtCountry" EventName="TextChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:PopupControlExtender ID="Panel1_PopupControlExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" Position="Bottom" PopupControlID = "pnlLocation" TargetControlID="txtCountry" />
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void chkLocation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strSelected = "";

    foreach (ListItem l in chkLocation.Items)
    {
        if (l.Selected)
        {
            strSelected += l.Text + " ,";
        }
    }

    //txtCountry.Text = strSelected;

    Panel1_PopupControlExtender.Commit(strSelected);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The panel closes when you click one of the checkboxes cause it has `AutoPostBack = "true"`.

To be able to select multiple checkboxes just set AutoPostBack to false, and then create a button near the CheckBoxList on which to click to do the asynchronous postback after you selected all the required checkboxes. For this to work you also need to set `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` on the button.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server" Skinid="longTextbox" AutoPostBack = "false" OnClientItemSelected="passtohidden()" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlLocation" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upLocation">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkLocation" SkinID ="chkColor" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "false" onselectedindexchanged="chkLocation_SelectedIndexChanged" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="submitButton" Text="Ok" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtCountry" EventName="TextChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:PopupControlExtender ID="Panel1_PopupControlExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" Position="Bottom" PopupControlID = "pnlLocation" TargetControlID="txtCountry" />
```